# Sum values from a list of string and create a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I want to calculate and sum all values from a sorted list of string like that

```
List<string> sortedList = new List<string>();
//name, number, weight
sortedList.Add("A,5,1");
sortedList.Add("A,3,2");
sortedList.Add("B,4,1");
sortedList.Add("B,6,2");

sortedList.Sort();
```

Input: (List l)

```
Output: (List<Dicionary<string,int>> result):

A ( (5*1)+ ( 3*2) )
B ( (4*1) + (6*2) )
```

---

```
new List of dictionary <string, int>

1 - dic["A" , 11]
2 - dic["B" , 16]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please read [ask].

Comment: Have you started writing any codes? What part of the code are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

Using linq you can do this.

```
Dictionary<string, int> r = sortedList.Select(x => x.Split(','))
    .GroupBy(x => x[0])
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(y => int.Parse(y[1])*int.Parse(y[2])));
```

First split all the string by `,`. then group them by first element of array. then convert them into dictionary. first element is key. and the value is sum of `element2*element3`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split string so you can get multiplication and key.
You can split using `Split` method. Also, you need to skip first element after splitting.

```
var multArray = sortedList.Select (x=>int.Parse (x.Split(',')[1])*int.Parse (x.Split(',')[2]));
var keyArray = sortedList.Select (x=>x.Split(',')[0]);
```

`multArray` is array with sums, and `keyarray` is array with keys. Then you need populate dictionary.

```
for (int i = 0; i  < keyArray.Count(); i ++) 
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey (keyArray[i])) 
    { 
        dictionary[keyArray[i]] += multArray [i];
    } 
    else
    {
        dictionary.Add (keyArray[i], multArray [i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: running your code do you get the following error 
`Error 1 Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'` did you test that prior to posting it as an answer

Comment: @MethodMan I'd forgotten to cast it. I updated post.

Comment: lots of unnecessary work especially with the for loop this could have all been done with less code using Lamda

Comment: @MethodMan I think it would become unreadable. Especially for newbies.